# R: Preferential Attachment Algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, graph-theory, igraph

I want (bit curious) to know is there any other algorithm possible for *preferential attachment network*. I want `R` code. I write something and that is work for me

**My Code**

```
t1 <- 50
int.adj.mat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0), nrow = 2) 
p <- c(0.5,0.5)
for (i in 2:t1) {
p <- rowSums(int.adj.mat)/sum(int.adj.mat)
d <- rbinom(i, 1, p)
int.adj.mat <- rbind(cbind(int.adj.mat, d), c(d,0))
}
PA <- matrix(0, nrow = NROW(int.adj.mat), ncol = NCOL(int.adj.mat))
for (i in 1:nrow(int.adj.mat)) {
PA[,i] <- int.adj.mat[,i]
}

library(igraph) #For plotting
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(PA, mode = "undirected")
plot(network, vertex.size = 3, vertex.label = NA)
```

**Output**

[image]

This code is actually increases the order of *adjacency matrix* when a new node is arrived in the pre-existing network. There are several article available see ([pa1](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Maksudul-Alam/publication/257589053_Distributed-Memory_Parallel_Algorithms_for_Generating_Massive_Scale-free_Networks_Using_Preferential_Attachment_Model/links/5630e17e08ae3de9381cc914/Distributed-Memory-Parallel-Algorithms-for-Generating-Massive-Scale-free-Networks-Using-Preferential-Attachment-Model.pdf) and [pa2](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/doc/ms/rndgen.pdf)) where author describe several algorithms. But it is hard to implement in `R`. Any improvised version of algorithm written in `R` is appreciated.

This question is completely for **self-study** and **knowledge** purpose.

Comment: This question is not phrased very clearly, but it seems that you are asking two things: (1) efficient algorithms for sampling from the preferential attachment model (2) implementations of these in R.  If you are looking to study graph algorithms, I strongly suggest you drop R. It is not a language suitable for algorithm development. It lacks many data structures that would be useful in that context and it makes it difficult to implement new non-trivial data structures.

Comment: The key to an efficient implementation is generating random variates from a _dynamically updated_ discrete distribution (probability of attachment is proportional to degrees, but degrees change as the graph grows). You can take a look at [igraph's psumtree data structure](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/core/psumtree.c), implemented in C, but also well commented and easy to follow.